# using service, android says "application keeps stopping", stopping is intentional

Tags: android, android-studio, service, operating-system

So I wrote an application, and it's only job is to start a service. The service is for a timer that doesn't run full screen. Anyway, it doesn't seem to be having any errors, but the Android operating system is complaining that "The application keeps stopping". I'm thinking that end users will see that and think it is a big deal. Is there any way to let the operating system know that the closure is intentional or am I just screwed because the apps only purpose is to open the service?

Comment: What is "the closure"? How are you doing it? Are you sure it isn't actually crashing? We need more details.

Comment: I think it might have actually been crashing. I was having an error with trying to unregister a receiver that wasn't registered. Pretty embarassing. Should I delete my question?